# How do you force python subplots to have equal widths and separate heights (gridspec isn't working)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following figure.  Equal aspect ratio for each of the axes is a requirement.  I'd love the widths to match between subplots and the height to be defined by the aspect ratio of the subplot.
[image: attempt1_subplot]

I attempted using GridSpec- total mess- it's impossible to shrink the whitespace to make a reasonable plot, so I've got to be doing something wrong:
[image: attempt2_gridspec]

```
left  = 0.125  
right = 0.9    
bottom = 0.2   
top = 0.9      
wspace = 0.1  
hspace = 0.1   

fig = plt.figure(5, figsize=(4, 12))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(5, 1,
                   width_ratios=[1,1,1,1,1],
                   height_ratios=[0.5,1.2,1,1.5,3])
plt.subplots_adjust(left=left,right=right,wspace=wspace,bottom=bottom,top=top,hspace=hspace)

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0],aspect='equal',xlim=[0,2],ylim=[0,0.5])
plt.plot(z,z,color='black',zorder=1)                                              
ax1.grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)
sc = plt.scatter(bob1[:-1,4],bob1[:-1,2],cmap=cmap,c=z,s=45,zorder=2)

ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1],aspect='equal',xlim=[0,1.5],ylim=[0,0.8])
plt.plot(z,z,color='black',zorder=1)                                              
ax2.grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)
major_ticks = np.arange(0, 1.4, 0.4)                                               
ax2.set_xticks(major_ticks)
ax2.set_yticks(major_ticks)
sc = plt.scatter(bob2[:-1,4],bob2[:-1,2],cmap=cmap,c=z,s=45,zorder=2)

ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[2],aspect='equal',xlim=[0,2],ylim=[0,1])
plt.plot(z,z,color='black',zorder=1)                                               
ax3.grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)
sc = plt.scatter(bob3[:-1,4],bob3[:-1,2],cmap=cmap,c=z,s=45,zorder=2)

ax4 = plt.subplot(gs[3],aspect='equal',xlim=[0,2],ylim=[0,1.5],zorder=2)
plt.plot(z,z,color='black',zorder=1)                                              
ax4.grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)
sc = plt.scatter(bob4[:-1,4],bob4[:-1,2],cmap=cmap,c=z,s=45,zorder=2)

ax5 = plt.subplot(gs[4],aspect='equal',xlim=[0,3],ylim=[0,3])
plt.plot(z,z,color='black',zorder=1)                                             
ax5.grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)
major_ticks = np.arange(0, 3, 1.0)                                               
ax5.set_xticks(major_ticks)
ax5.set_yticks(major_ticks)
sc = plt.scatter(bob5[:-1,4],bob5[:-1,2],cmap=cmap,c=z,s=45,zorder=2)

cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.8, 0.3, 0.03, 0.4])
cbar = fig.colorbar(sc, cax=cbar_ax)
cbar.set_ticks([0,6.45,13])
cbar.set_ticklabels([14,7,0])
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51836629/set-width-of-plot-and-infer-height-from-aspect-ratio-of-subplots

Answer (score -1):

This is what I do when I want different height sub-plots that (usually, in my case) share the x axis:

fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, gridspec_kw=dict(height_ratios=[1,3]))

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.02) # etc

Comment: Thanks for your help @user2223275!  Sounds reasonable, but when I run the code I get the error message: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gridspec_kw'.  I'm using python 2.7, I imported matplotlib as plt.  That should cover it, right?

Comment: Hi. I also use 2.7. Here is a complete script that works for me.

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, sharex=True, figsize=(8,11),

                      gridspec_kw=dict(height_ratios=[1,1,3]))
                      
                      
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.02, top=0.94, right=0.95, bottom=0.06)


ax[0].plot([1,2,3], [4,3,1], 'o-')

ax[1].plot([1,2,3], [1,6,2], 'o-')

ax[2].plot([1,2,3], [5,3,8], 'o-')

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. I am using matplotlib 2.7.8.

Comment: Be sure you are calling plt.subplots (with the plural, 's') and not plt.subplot.