# Set width of plot and infer height from aspect ratio of subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I often have to create plots which have a fixed width (e.g. the column width of an article) and whose subplots have a fixed ratio in the data coordinate system. I want to set the width manually and obtain a plot with this chosen width, aspect ratio of the subplots and the appropriate height.

**Example**: The columns of an article have a width of 8.5cm. I want to create a plot with two subplots (axes) and for both axes the option `ax.set_aspect("equal")` is chosen so that 1 unit on the `y` axis takes the same physical space as one unit on the `x` axis.
My plot should now have a total width of 8.5cm but the height should be calculated from matplotlib by taking into account the aspect ratio of the subplots as well as the `xlim` and `ylim` values.

How can I achieve this?

Additionally, how do I make sure that the font size used in the plots is the same as in the article? So if my article is set with "times" in 11pt, how do I get the same font with the same size in my plot? I tried to use

```
params = {'text.usetex': True,
          'font.size': 11,
          'font.family': 'times',
          'text.latex.unicode': True,
          }
plt.rcParams.update(params)
```

but for example the x- and y-label fonts in my plot are now much larger than in the article. I thought that 'font.size' updates all font sizes?

Comment: Do the plots have the same x and y limits? Else another constraint is needed.

Comment: If `ax1` and `ax2` dont have the same limits, the aspect of both of them should still be "equal" but now the physical size of 1 unit would be different between the two subplots. But both `ax1` and `ax2` should occupy the same width (or ideally: one could provide a fixed size in cm or a ratio between the two).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the height of the figure given the width and the subplot parameters. The following assumes that the subplots are equal in width and that there is only one row of subplots and that they all have a defined aspect (i.e. not "auto").

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(8.5,8.5))
for ax in (ax1, ax2):
    ax.set_aspect("equal")

ax1.plot([1,3], [4,6], marker="o")
ax2.plot([26,84], [64,-13], marker="s")

def resize(axes):
    # this assumes a fixed aspect being set for the axes.
    for ax in axes:
        if ax.get_aspect() == "auto":
            return
        elif ax.get_aspect() == "equal":
            ax.set_aspect(1)
    fig = axes[0].figure
    s = fig.subplotpars
    n = len(axes)
    axw = fig.get_size_inches()[0]*(s.right-s.left)/(n+(n-1)*s.wspace)
    r = lambda ax: np.diff(ax.get_ylim())[0]/np.diff(ax.get_xlim())[0]*ax.get_aspect()
    a = max([r(ax) for ax in axes])
    figh = a*axw/(s.top-s.bottom)
    fig.set_size_inches(fig.get_size_inches()[0],figh)

resize((ax1,ax2))

plt.show()
```